# How can I fix an exeption Agora in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, agora.io

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':agora_rtc_engine:parseDebugLocalResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':agora_rtc_engine:androidApis'.
> Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-31\android.jar.
> C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-31\android.jar

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 55s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1